# Asp.Net MVC core Identity Framwork 6.0 customizing table column is not reflecting in User class

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, entity-framework-core

I am developing a Asp.Net MVC application using framework 6.0 with Core Identity Razer pages in code first approach. I modified the AspNetUsers Table with my own table definition and successfully migrated into database. Also I have customized the AspNetUser column in DBContext.cs, But still Its throwing Invalid column error after CreateAsync operation executed. Am I doing something wrong or missing anything? Why the customization is not reflecting in CreateUser class?

Comment: Hi @user17598374, which line makes error?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.